# How call a behavior of variable that is explained by other variable?

Tags: interaction, terminology, mediation

I have one dependent variable (it is a binary response variable that I want to predict, let's say "t1"), and also two independent variables ("v1" and "v2"). They are both found statistically significant in univariate analysis as contributors to t1 response odds.

Additionally, we preliminary know that v1 is a drug that used to elevate v2.

When I create multivariate analysis using logistic regression only with v1+v2 as independent variables and t1 as dependent variable, v1 (the drug) is losing significance as I expected.

What do I call this behavior?
Is v1 called [mediator variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)#Direct_versus_indirect_effects), and if so, how do I call v2?

Comment: What does _losing significance_ mean for you? Just that a P-value decreases or are you focusing on whether there is (is not) significance at some critical level (e.g. 5%)?

Comment: Is v1 a drug dosage rather than a drug itself?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that your logistic regression is $logodds =\beta_0+\beta_1 v_1+\beta_2(v_1+v_2)?$

Comment: @NickCox the P-value goes from under critical level 0.05 to 0.4

Comment: @AgnesianOperator its a binary variable for exposure to drugs that elevate blood pressure (vasopressors), and v2 is mean arterial pressure in mmHg

Comment: @Dave Thank you :) If I understood correctly, you wrote equation with interaction, but I used a simple regression with v1 and v2 as independent variables without interaction variable (just added them to the model using SPSS GUI): =0+11+22

Comment: Opinion: I would talk about these variables in a structural causal model without making special names for them. Your nodes would be V={t1,v1,v2} with edges E={(v1, v2), (v1, t1), (v2, t1)}. See Judea Pearl's work for elaboration.

Comment: @arielhasidim There is no interaction in the equation I gave. Interactions involve products of variables, and no product of variables is not present in my equation.

Comment: thank you @AgnesianOperator, I will read more about causal models, but I'm not sure how much it suits me because it's not customary in clinical medicine research as much as I know

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding @Dave. I find it difficult to interpret the equation and why '2(1+2)' element has the sum of variables, but I know this is a simple logistic regression with v1 and v2 as different independent variable with a similar role, so its probably more like this:  =0+11+22